# magnetism in metallic alloys

Tags: magnetism

i am working with a multicomponent alloy system for soft magnetic application,it is iron based and have composition of Fe Mn Si B Mo,how can i calculate the net magnetic moment or saturation magnetization of the system,consider proper mixing of alloys in melt takes place.
kindly tell me the theoritical way of calculating,and individual contribution